# Push notification Registration using Http Post Request

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobilepush-android

Using Salesforce SDK I achieved Push notification. To use my own login UI I used Http Get request to get access token. So I need a Http post request to register [https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/MobilePushServiceDevicedevice for push notification. I Used](https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/MobilePushServiceDevice)  as url and added post data like :

```
HttpPost postMethod=new HttpPost(url);
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);                       
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ConnectionToken", registrationId));          
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ServiceType", "androidGcm"));            
postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

But response for the post request is

> [{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}]

Please provide necessary advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you found a solution? I've the same problem... :(

Comment: Did  you find any solution to this ? When I am requesting to this url, I am getting "Invalid session id" error. I am passing session id in header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to use `https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/MobilePushServiceDevice/`

instead of

`https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/MobilePushServiceDevice`

this way I resolved my issue.

Comment: The request is being made by SDK internally, how can I change the url manually? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

MobilePushServiceDevice object is only accessible by the sessions created with the Consumer Key of the push enabled connected application. If you already made push notifications work with Salesforce Mobile SDK, you probably already have your push enabled connected application set up, so use this connected application's consumer key to create Oauth session.

Comment: Thank You for the replay. I resolved my issue and answer is given below. Can you please check this issue once : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/75473/getting-push-notification-multiple-time