# Getting Push Notification multiple time

Tags: salesforce1-app, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I have created Apex Trigger for inserting and updating Opportunity for android app. After login I am registering device for push notification and adding registration Id to MobilePushServiceDevice table in salesforce. If user uninstall the app we cannot unregister the device. If I don't unregister the device do I get multiple notification on creating the opportunity? Because sometime I am getting multiple notification while creating the opportunity .

Answer (score 0):

If the same device is registered by 2 users and your Apex trigger sends push notification to both of them, then 2 push notifications will be sent to the device.

Comment: In my case same user register same device more than one time.

Comment: Is this iOS or Android device? APNS device token doesn't change often, so when the same user registers the same device token, new registration record is not created, instead the old record is updated. You can check which devices user currently has registered by following these steps: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pushImplGuide.meta/pushImplGuide/pns_check_user_device_registrations.htm

Comment: It's Android device so if we register same device multiple time we will get multiple access token.